# Bluetooth 4.0 based application development on HTC One x or other

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcom

I am looking into making the HTC One X work with a ble heart rate monitor. Do you think this would be possible? should I try to develop an app that can pair the phone with the device using the Broadcom SDK that supporst Bluetooth 4.0 ? Which kind of API shold I use ? What are all the other Android Mobile phones can support Bluetooth 4.0 with Broadcom BLE . Is the HTC One X supports by Broadcom BLE ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BLE is supported by HTC devices starting with the HTC One X+ and the HTC Droid DNA. There is a high level Java API available as an SDK add-on for BLE. For more information inquire at http://htcdev.com.

Comment: yeah, the htc ble api doesnt seen to have been shipped with the HTC One X (just with One X+ and One) and Im not sure if it possible to use it as their [faq](https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/bluetooth-smart/ble-faq/) does not mention HTC One X as supported